# How to get the value of an element only if another specific element is visible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, cypress-each

**What I am working with:**

```
<ul class="abc">
 <li class="xyz">
  <a href="www.something.com">
   <div>
    <h2>
     <div>
      <div class="theText">
       <div>Get this text</DIV>
      </div>
     </div>
    </h2>
   </div>
  </a> 
  <button aria-label="remove">...</button>
 </li>
 <li class="xyz">...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
 <li class="xyz">...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
 <li class="xyz">...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
</ul>
```

The `button` here has two states for the `aria-label` attribute which is remove (for when the button is clicked) and add (for when the button is not yet clicked).

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to get the value within the `<a>` tag, which in this case is "Get this text", **BUT** only if the button within its same `<li>` tag is set to `aria-label="remove"`. I will also be storing the values that I get within an array to later on compare with another array.

**What I have tried:**

```
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').each(($element) => {
    cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').within(($element) => {
        cy.wrap($element)
            .find('button[aria-label="remove"]')
            .find('div[class="theText"]')
            .invoke('text').then(text => {
                myArray.push(text)
            })
    })
}).then(() => {
    cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})
```

With the above code, I am getting this [Assertion Error from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6LGW.jpg).

Comment: Haven't used cypress. However if I understand but first why don't you do cy.get('li.xyz')? Also You are querying all the specific li items and for each one you are trying to find another `.xyz` element? however based on the provided markup no other .xyz exist

Comment: @ManosKounelakis - All the other `<li>` tags have the same `class="xyz"`. Let me update the post, thanks for that.

Comment: You can remove the `cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').within()` line since you are wrapping `$element` and using `.find()` - within and find do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `:has()` pseudo-selector, you should do so on the outer of the `.each()` loop.

But please ***beware***, `:has()` pseudo-selector **will fail** if there are zero buttons already clicked.

```js
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]:has(button[aria-label="remove"])')  // implied filter
  .each($li => {
    // only element with remove attribute inside here
    cy.wrap($li)
      .find('div[class="theText"]')
      .invoke('text')
      .then(text => {
        myArray.push(text)
      })
  })
}).then(() => {
  cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [cypress-if package](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if)

```js
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').each(($element) => {
  cy.wrap($element).within(() => {    

    cy.get('button[aria-label="remove"]')
      .if()                     // any chained commands will only run 
                                // if [aria-label="remove"] exists
                                // but the test does not fail 
                                // if [aria-label="remove"] does not exist
      
      .parent()                 // move up to parent to avoid your error msg
      .find('div[class="theText"] div')
      .invoke('text').then(text => {
        myArray.push(text)
      })
  })
}).then(() => {
  cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})

cy.get('@myArray')
  .should('deep.eq', ['Get this text'])    // passes
```

---

**Sample HTML for testing**

```html
<ul class="abc">
  <li class="xyz">
    <a href="www.something.com">
      <div>
        <h2>
          <div>
            <div class="theText">
              <div>Get this text</DIV>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <button aria-label="remove">...</button>
  </li>
  <li class="xyz">
    <a href="www.somethingelse.com">
      <div>
        <h2>
          <div>
            <div class="theText">
              <div>Not this text</DIV>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <button aria-label="add">...</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Result**: ['Get this text']

---

**Note** I added and extra `div` here `.find('div[class="theText"] div')` to avoid whitespace around the text, but it doesn't alter the conditional check.

Comment: I tried this and the test still went through all of the `<button>` elements that didn't have `[aria-label="remove"]`. I also ran this without clicking the buttons so that the `[aria-label="remove"]` would not exist. The test still went through all of the `<button>` elements anyway. Any advise on this?

Comment: You have a bug somewhere, it works for me - will add the sample I tested it on.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "old" way to do conditional checking, but the `.if()` command is better because it has built-in retry when loading asynchronous data.

```js
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').each(($element) => {

  // Use jquery to check the button has remove attribute
  const removeButton = $element.find('button[aria-label="remove"]')
  if (removeButton.length) {

    cy.wrap($element).find('div[class="theText"]')
      .invoke('text').then(text => {
        myArray.push(text)
      })
  }
}).then(() => {
  cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) in your selector

```
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]:has(button[aria-label="remove"])').each(($element) => {
    cy.get('li[class="xyz"]:has(button[aria-label="remove"])').within(($element) => {
        cy.wrap($element)
            .find('div[class="theText"]')
            .invoke('text').then(text => {
                myArray.push(text)
            })
    })
}).then(() => {
    cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})
```

Or you can use [`parentsUntil`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parentsuntil) to get back to the parent element after finding the related element with `aria-label="remove"`

```
let myArray: any = []

cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').each(($element) => {
    cy.get('li[class="xyz"]').within(($element) => {
        cy.wrap($element)
            .find('button[aria-label="remove"]')
            .parentsUntil('li[class="xyz"]')
            .find('div[class="theText"]')
            .invoke('text').then(text => {
                myArray.push(text)
            })
    })
}).then(() => {
    cy.wrap(myArray).as('myArray')
})
```

Comment: I tried `has` - This works but it goes through all the `<button>` elements even if it does not have `[aria-label="remove"]`, here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/fcEGOAL). This makes the duration of the test longer. Do you have any advise? | 
As for trying `parentsUntil` - No luck with this and getting [this Assertion Error](https://imgur.com/wF5sq97). It does detect the button, but fails on the `.parentUntil` command.

Comment: I modified my answer with `has` in the first `cy.get` as well. I think it would help you to check elements with certain conditions only. @krisc

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myArray = []

const buttonCheck = document.querySelector("button").getAttribute("aria-label");
    
if(buttonCheck === "remove"){
   const aTagInnerText = document.querySelector("a").innerText;
   myArray.push(aTagInnerText.trim(" "));
}

console.log(myArray)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>
<body>
<ul class="abc">
 <li class="xyz">
  <a href="www.something.com">
   <div>
    <h2>
     <div>
      <div class="theText">
       <div>Get this text</DIV>
      </div>
     </div>
    </h2>
   </div>
  </a> 
  <button aria-label="remove">...</button>
 </li>
 <li>...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
 <li>...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
 <li>...Same stuff here as above li...</li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).